# SSRS Chart with a Matrix

Tags: matrix, graph, charts, reporting-services, reporting

I have following Matrix and chart created. Currently the chart uses Sum(PO_COUNT). Matrix uses the expression, =(Sum(Fields!PO_COUNT.Value)/Sum(Fields!PO_COUNT.Value,"TEAM"))*100 for Data section. Matrix presents data as percent of row total. The chart need to use the same data field as the Matrix .The chart need to present the same data and values as Matrix. If I change the chart's values section to use the expression =(Sum(Fields!PO_COUNT.Value)/Sum(Fields!PO_COUNT.Value,"TEAM"))*100, it gives me the following error message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmHdi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk4bt.png)

I re-wrote the expression based on the error message but none worked

Comment: Show your chart series and category properties, there is not enough info here at the moment. Also, when posting error messages, please use text, not an image. If somebody wants to research the error they would have to copy it manually.

Comment: I have included two images here. First image shows the chart and its related matrix

Comment: Also, mock up what you actually want the chart to look like, from what you have said so far, it seems you could just use a 100% stacked chart and then you would not need to calculate anything for the chart

Comment: Thanks Alan. That simply solve the problem

Comment: If it is not 100% stack bar,  we may need to write an expression

Comment: I'll add this as an answer so you can accept and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have said so far, it seems you could just use a 100% stacked chart and then you would not need to calculate anything for the chart

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood what you are trying to do (post samples if that's the case). Then there is no need to use an expression to calculate the percentages in the chart.

In this exmaple, I built a simple table with `Dept`, `EmpID` and `Salary`. There is a table to show the sum of each `Dept` and the percentage of the total dataset.

Here is the sample data created in the dataset query.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Dept varchar(20), EmPID int, Salary money)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
  ('Sales', 1, 30000), ('Sales', 2, 35000), ('Sales', 3, 36000)
, ('Finance', 4, 40000), ('Finance', 5, 40000), ('Finance', 6, 40000)
, ('Marketing', 7, 50000), ('Marketing', 8, 50000), ('Marketing', 9, 50000)
, ('Software', 10, 5000), ('Software', 11, 5000), ('Software', 12, 5000)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

The 3rd column is the expression similar to the one you are using (I'm just not multiplying by 100 as I format the textbox instead)

[image]

That gives the following result

[image]

Next I added a simple pie chart with the following settings

[image]

**Note:** There is no expression on the value, it's just sum of salary, as it's a pie chart it will always represent a percentage of the total..

Finally, I assume you want to show the actual % on the chart.

To do this, select the value series and expand the "Label" section. Set the `UseValueAsLabel` property to `False` and then set the `Label` property to `#PERCENT`

[image]

The final output looks like this.

[image]